# Any shortest method to get RHS values in the string with comma separated

Tags: java, string, parsing

This is my String

```
String str = "fus=""192.10.136.111"""," ful=""333333"""," fui=""7b7b7b40000000010000012e55192ab8""", fuc=1, fuq=3, fut=2015-03-30 16:21:36, fud=1, fss=3, fst=2," fsi=""302""", fso=0, fsa=0, fsr=2, cuc=1".
```

I need only the RHS values without double quotes with comma seperated. For example

```
192.10.136.111,333333,7b7b7b40000000010000012e55192ab8,1,3,2015-03-30 16:21:36,1,3,2,302,0,0,2,1
```

The logic should be generic

Comment: This code won't compile.. Please post code that compiles

Comment: you'll need to escape the quotation marks within the string for it to compile.

Comment: oh, that is ok, i just gave that as an example.

Comment: Your code (although very limited) is not compilable. Please sort the problem and edit the question. Though we have understood the question, we can't help since you have not provided correct and compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like below (which is basically a CSV of key-value pair)

```
String str = "fus=\"192.168.1.1\",fus1=\"333333\"";
```

You can use below code

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
String [] keyValuePairs = str.split(",");
for(String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs) {
    String [] keyValue = keyValuePair.split("=");
    values.add(keyValue[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that this is only your second question, you need to get into a habit of providing [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You posted your problem, but you didn't post an attempt or even an explanation of an attempt.

Having said that, after escaping all of the quotations in your string, you could try simple string manipulations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "fus=\"\"192.10.136.111\"\"\",\" ful=\"\"333333\"\"\",\" fui=\"\"7b7b7b40000000010000012e55192ab8\"\"\", fuc=1, fuq=3, fut=2015-03-30 16:21:36, fud=1, fss=3, fst=2,\" fsi=\"\"302\"\"\", fso=0, fsa=0, fsr=2, cuc=1";
    String[] pieces = str.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        pieces[i] = pieces[i].substring(pieces[i].indexOf("=") + 1).replaceAll("\"", "");
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(",", pieces));
}
```

Results:

[image]